# Get ID from dynamic button with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have php file for get value from database.
i have trouble get an id button dynamical from the result.
Am i doing wrong?

this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script>src="jquery-3.3.1.js"</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <?php
        include("koneksi.php");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM data_cv";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        ?>
        <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nama</th>
                    <th>Nomor Identitas</th>
                    <th>Tempat Lahir</th>
                    <th>Tanggal Lahir</th>
                    <th>Jenis SIM</th>
                    <th>Masa SIM</th>
                    <th>Nomor SKCK</th>
                    <th>Pendidikan</th>
                    <th>Nomor Telepon (Handphone)</th>
                    <th>Keterangan</th>
                    <th>Terima Berkas</th>
                    <th>Tindakan</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '
                <tr>
                <td>'.$row["nama"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["id_ktp"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["tempat_lahir"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["tanggal_lahir"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["jenis_sim"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["masa_sim"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["no_skck"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["pendidikan"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["no_telp"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["keterangan"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["terima_berkas"].'</td>
                <td><button id= "'.$row['id_ktp'].'" value="Accept"">Panggil</button></td>
                </tr>
                ';
            }
            $conn->close();
            ?>
            <script>
            $("button").click(function() {
            alert(this.id);
            });
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my php file result is this

[image: php file result]

i want when i click the button, i get alert from their id base on php values.
please give me advice.

Comment: Well this line isn't going to help: `<script>src="jquery-3.3.1.js"</script>`. Are you sure you don't have jQuery errors in the console? Also the `value="Accept"` in your `<button>` has a trailing `"`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge i have replace with <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and remove the value still not working

Comment: `<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/…>` is wrong, unless you have that folder `./ajax.googleapis.com` locally. your missing the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use an `id` instead use [`data-`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) attributes, then use a class to target the buttons, for example:

`<button data-id="'.$row['id_ktp'].'" class="valueButton"></button>`

Then in your jQuery you can get the value using the data api.

```
<script>
$(".valueButton").click(function() {
  alert($(this).data('id'));
});
</script>
```

---

I over overlooked the following:

- The script tag is wrong `<script>src="jquery-3.3.1.js"</script>`
- Missing `<tbody>`
- And careful with them auto's """ which some editors just add in as you type to keep you on your toes.